# Как стандартными способами c++11 записать файл в utf-8

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, c++11, потоки-данных

А именно использую `ofstream` и в самом файле записывается русскими буками хорошо, а вот с названием документа проблемы. Что только не пробовал, название файла получается что-то вроде такого `�.txt (неверная кодировка)`

---

Может я не совсем правильно задал вопрос, мне нужно чтобы программа сохраняла `txt` файл с названиями `аа.txt` `аб.txt` `ав.txt` - ... - `яя.txt`

Кратко расскажу суть программы: Есть словарь слов, расположенный в алфавитном порядке, программа должна разбить этот словарь по **33*33** документам (Минус **3*32**, нет слов начинающихся с ь,ы,ъ). Документ `аб.txt` будет иметь все слова начинающиеся с **аб...**

Запись в файлы корректная, единственное, что названия файлов неправильные

Вот моя функция `main()`:

```
int main() {
    if (rfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(rfile, line)) {
            string first, second;
            try {
                first = line[0];
                second = line[1];
            }catch (...) {
                continue;
            }
            if (first == " " || first == "." || first == "-" || first == "|" || first == "," ||
                second == " " || second == "|" || second == "-" || second == "." || second == ",")
                continue;
            string wfilename = first + second + ".txt";
            ofstream wfile;
            wfile.open(wdirectory + wfilename, ios_base::app);
            if (wfile.is_open())
                wfile << line;
            wfile.close();
        }
        rfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Система `Linux mint x64`

---

Решение найдено! Я брал первые две буквы строки и использовал их для составления названия. Чтобы все корректно работало, нужно было конвертировать исходный файл в `utf-8`.
На `linux` эта команда выглядит как `iconv -f windows-1251 < /home/user/filename.txt > /home/user/newEncodedFilename.txt`
Знаки `<` и `>` обязательны. Далее уже использовать новый файл. Спасибо `sercxjo`

Comment: Покажите как вы записываете в файл русские буквы.

Comment: Какая ОС. У Windows есть два режима ANSI и OEM. Может у вас OEM кодировка? Скопируйте как точно выглядит ваше имя файла. Посмотрите как выглядят символы 128, 140, 160, 200, 220 - тогда будет понятно в какой кодировки понимается имя файла. Попробуйте байтами "забить" UTF-8 имя "\xD0\xA4\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB9\xD0\xBB.txt" Если буквы русские - то вам нужно думать о переводе в UTF-8, если нет - у вас другая кодировка.

Comment: @nick а как посмотреть? В дебагере?

Comment: Не получится в дебагере. wfile.open("\x80.txt",ios_base:app) так получится. Когда поймёте какая кодировка - тогда уже проще. Хотя, может и в дебаге посоздавать файлов с разными именами что б не пересобирать проэкт.

Comment: @nick попробовал, получается `�.txt (неверная кодировка)`

Comment: @nick а вот это `xD0xA4xD0xB0xD0xB9xD0xBB.txt` даёт `файл.txt`. И в дебагере кстати точно так же показываются русские строки

Comment: Если совсем не получается, я могу вам скинуть в хексе весь алфавит utf8

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40648/discussion-between-herrgott-and-nick-n-a).

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); и будет счастье

Comment: @Цовак не будет, сразу же попробовал

Comment: плюс, еще `setlocale(0, "");` и `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus")`  аналогично

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Русские буквы в utf-8 обычно занимают 2 байта. Выбирая первые два байта из строки вы скорее всего получите только одну русскую букву, но возможно если первый из них другой символ или длина utf-8-представления символа более 2 байт, некорректно прерывается последовательность utf-8 кодировки. Для первого байта последовательности (x&192)==192, для остальных (x&192)==128. По этим признакам можно вырезать первую и вторую буквы (точнее в первом байте указывается длина последовательности в единичной системе исчисления, но будем надеяться на правильность исходных данных).
Таким образом, найти длину символа поможет функция:

```
int wlen(const string &x, int start)
{
    if(x[start]==0) return 0;
    if((x[start]&192)!=192) return 1;
    int i=1;
    while((x[start+i]&192)==128) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Теперь остаётся заменить получение первого и второго символов строки:

```
first = line.substr(0, wlen(line, 0));
second = line.substr(first.size(), wlen(line, first.size()));
```

Ну и далее можно добавить анализ, что `first.size()==0 || second.size()==0`

Из беседы в чате выяснилось, что исходный файл в кодировке windows-1251.
Чтобы привести его в кодировку принятую в Linux Mint можно использовать команду `iconv`:

```
iconv -f windows-1251 < исходный_файл > новый_файл
```

Если требуется включить перекодировку в саму программу, можно использовать libiconv [пример](https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/iconv_c.txt.html).

Comment: все равно в дебаггере `first = <incomplete sequence \340>`
`second` то же самое
`wfilename = "\340\340.txt"`

Comment: а какая при этом исходная строка?

Comment: `абдикация [отречение; отказ от сана и власти правителя, сложение с себя
      этого звания (Даль)] см. отказ`

Comment: Может быть у вас не в utf-8 кодировка? Как line выглядит в том же месте в дебагере?

Comment: `"\347\340\362\377\355\363\362\356\351|\347\340\342\377\347\340\355\355\356\351\r"`

Comment: ну я не в этом месте именно поймал, просто поставил на паузу дебагер через определенное время, т.к. в начальных этапах `line` пустой

Comment: это не utf-8, попробуйте сконвертировать файл `iconv -f windows-1251`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40656/discussion-between-sercxjo-and-herrgott).

Answer (score 4):

Проверяйте вашу системную локаль и что именно содержится в файлах. Ибо всё прекрасно работает:

**1**:

```
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ ls ф*
ффф.текст

$ cat ффф.текст 
ффф.результат

$ ./a.out
ффф.результат

$ ls ф*
ффф.результат  ффф.текст
```

**2**:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream rfile;
    rfile.open( "ффф.текст" );
    std::string line;
    getline(rfile, line);
    rfile.close();

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    std::ofstream wfile;
    wfile.open( line.c_str() );
    wfile.close();
}
```

Comment: читает, русский язык тоже читает как ни странно. Пробовал вчера простой `cout << "Лол";` выводил кракозябры

Comment: Тут могут быть два варианта: либо системная локаль не UTF-8, либо исходник с "Лол" в другой кодировке. P.S. Что он "читает" в примере - не так важно, важно какой файл создаётся.

Comment: Так я и не понял что мне делать. Как сохранять файл с русским названием и содержанием?

Comment: Для начала - прочитать мой ответ, выполнить пошагово то, что в нём содержится. Начиная с первой команды (проверить свою локаль). Потом - создать файл `ффф.текст`, записать в него строчку `ффф.результат`. Собрать и запустить исходник. Посмотреть что он выведет. Потом посмотреть на результат команды `ls ф*` в каталоге запуска. Доложить. (ничего, что я только что переписал свой ответ заново? в третий раз этого делать не буду, sorry...)

Comment: Да без разницы чем собирать. Дальше что происходит? Хотя командную строку gcc и вывод тоже можно показать.

Comment: в дебагере посмотрите, что в переменной с именем лежит?

Comment: добрался до `./a.out`. Я так понимаю имеется в виду скопмилированная программа, но я не могу её скомпилировать через `gcc`, выдает ошибки, хотя в `ide` собирается. Под `g++` собралась на ура. Последний шаг работает